# tfs 2013.3 team alerts not working

Tags: tfs

i have seen similar issues to ours, tho non of them seem to be related to this issue:
using tfs 2013 update 3, all users are from AD. when i make a new alert under team alerts no one from the team seems to be getting any alerts. 
only personal alert work.
[image]
any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to upgrade your TFS2013.3 to the latest edition TFS2013.5.
2. Make sure the Teams belong to **Contributors** group.

Comment: they all belong to Contributors. i will try to upgarde.. and report back .thanks